# Javascript - filter if statement doesnt work

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hey guys i got this code where i wanted filter array and return only if doesnt equal to type RJ_TIME and seatClassKey TRAIN_1ST_CLASS at same time.

This doesnt work and behave like OR, so it will return me object that isnt RJ_TIME or TRAIN_1ST_CLASS.

```
.filter((pClass) => { 
  if (isFirstClassSoldOut) {
    if (pClass.type !== "RJ_TIME" && pClass.seatClassKey !== "TRAIN_1ST_CLASS") {     
      return pClass  
    }
  } else {
    return pClass
  }
})
.map((pClass) => (
```

Comment: Can you include the input and desired output?

Comment: you need to return either true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in the callback for `filter` needs return a boolean value which is what `filter` uses to determine whether the iterated element is returned or not.

Here only objects 2 & 4 will be returned as they're the only objects whose properties match the condition.

```js
const isFirstClassSoldOut = true;

const arr = [
  { type: 'RJ_TIME', seatClassKey: 'TRAIN_1ST_CLASS' },
  { type: 'RJ_TIME2', seatClassKey: 'TRAIN_1ST_CLASS2' },
  { type: 'RJ_TIME3', seatClassKey: 'TRAIN_1ST_CLASS' },
  { type: 'RJ_TIME4', seatClassKey: 'TRAIN_1ST_CLASS4' },
];

arr.filter(pClass => { 
  return isFirstClassSoldOut
    && (pClass.type !== 'RJ_TIME'
      && pClass.seatClassKey !== 'TRAIN_1ST_CLASS');
})
.map(pClass => console.log(pClass));
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what ive been missing!

Comment: could you return only first object somehow in this case because its matched both conditions? (RJTIME and 1STCLASS)

Comment: It doesn't match the condition though. It matches both `RUN_TIME` and `TRAIN_1ST_CLASS`. The condition is NOT those values which is what you wanted. If you wanted it to match that condition change the `!==`s to `===`s. @DanielBílek

Comment: Sry my english is bad. but i figured it out. If i replace && with || it will me return all objects without first one which  one got both RJ_TIME and TRAIN_1ST_CLASS, but dont understand why :D

Comment: Because the first object's values DON'T match the condition. All the other objects have _at least one value_ that doesn't match, and therefore satisfy the condition. @DanielBílek